# Displaying maximum range over a hexagon map

Tags: ios, logic

I would like to show a maximum movement overlay in my hex map. For example:

Center point is at 50,50
Maximum allowed movement is 5 hexes.

This is the code I use for overlay:

```
for (int height = lowHeight; height <= highHeight; height++)
{
    for (int width = lowWidth; width <= highWidth; width++)
    {
        [self hexOnMap:height :width :@"green"];
    }
}
```

width being xCoordinate 50
height being yCoordinate 50

lowHeight = height - 5

highHeight = height + 5

lowWidth = width - 5

hightWidth = width + 5

Obviously my loop is not working as the corners are more than 5 hexes in movement. As I feel my IQ having dropping by the minute, someone please show me the obvious :) And the movement value of 5 is NOT static.

[image]

EDIT: @DPenner

Thanks for your reply. I tried something similar but this cursed thing still refuses to work. Your code displays this result:

[image]

EDIT 2: @DPenner - You ALMOST had it. I am uploading the overlay with your code so you can see. I ended up finding a great article last night which gave me the clues I needed to solve this problem. BUT I REALLY appreciate your help and trying to solve this!!!

[image]

Comment: Origin is: x=50 y=50 / Top: 50,49 / Top right: 51,49 / Bottom right: 51,50 / Bottom: 50,51 / Bottom left: 49,50 / Top left: 49,49.   I have x and y at zero in the top left corner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After almost 24 hours of no sleep, I found a great article dealing with exactly this issue. The article is here:

http://keekerdc.com/2011/03/hexagon-grids-coordinate-systems-and-distance-calculations/

and here is the code to make it all work:

```
for (int y = minY; y <= maxY; y++)
{
    for (int x = minX; x <= maxX; x++)
    {
        int xDistance = (x - startXcoordinate);

        int yStart = 0;
        if(x > startXcoordinate)
            yStart = -1;

        int yDistance = ((xDistance * -1) + yStart) / 2;

        yDistance = yDistance + (y - startYcoordinate);

        int z = (xDistance + yDistance)* -1 ;


        int maxDistance = 0;

        if(abs(xDistance) > maxDistance)
            maxDistance = abs(xDistance);

        if(abs(yDistance) > maxDistance)
            maxDistance = abs(yDistance);

        if(abs(z) > maxDistance)
            maxDistance = abs(z);

        if(abs(maxDistance) <= patrolRange)
            [self hexOnMap:y :x :@"green"];
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've deleted my old answer since it was completely wrong: I forgot to consider that adjacent hexes can sometimes differ in both x and y coordinates. Catching that is tricky but the following code should work:

If the center X coordinate is even:

```
for (int width = lowWidth; width <= highWidth; width++)
{        
    double heightNeeded = 5 - abs((centerX - width)/2.0);
    for (int height = centerY - (int)ceil(heightNeeded); height <= centerY + (int)floor(heightNeeded); height++)
    {
        [self hexOnMap:height :width :@"green"];
    }
}
```

If the center X coordinate is odd, swap the floor and ceiling functions. Change the 5 for a different sized overlay.

I checked it by hand, and it seemed to work fine. The outer loop is the width/X loop since its the X coordinates that zigzag across horizontally, which the ceil and floor functions "fix" in the inner height/Y loop.